# Direction of magnetic field in and out of a loop using the Right Hand Rule

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

The picture shows a question that I am struggling to understand. There was a post from earlier this year about this, but I could not understand the explanation. I cannot understand the distinction between what is inside and outside of the loop. In other words, how is it that the direction is out the page outside of the loop? Like how do I differentiate finding the current in and out of the loop if I am curling my fingers around the same wire? I understand that my thumb points in the direction of the current and then my fingers curl around the wire, but cannot understand what I described. I hope this makes sense[image: 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0K2R.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify what it is about the diagram you find confusing?
I think maybe you are confused because the picture shows (via x's and dots) the magnetic field *in the plane* of the loop. Perhaps you are confused about "inside and outside" the loop because you are trying to picture this scenario in three dimension. Try imagining this loop is floating on some water. If you try using the right hand rule is there a region where you will always be dipping your fingers into the water? and a complementary region where your fingers will always be coming out of the water? Don't worry too much about what happens well above and well beneath the surface of the water, although that is also something you should try to understand eventually.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean when you say that there is a region coming into and out of the water, but when I do this, it changes for the left side and the right side of that loop since the current is going down on the right and up on the left. So how does this mean that the direction of the magnetic field is always going in within the loop, and how do I use this logic to find the direction outside the loop?

Comment: @val0099 Just to clarify, are you saying there is some point on the loop where you can placed your *right* thumb in the direction of current and do not observe the magnetic flux going inward inside the loop and outward outside the loop? If so where is that point? If you are just confused about whether or not your other fingers will be going into or out of the page, try rotating your hand with your thumb fixed until your fingers come into or out of the page/water (sometimes this requires a good deal of flexibility).

Comment: Oh my gosh I finally understand this. Thank you soooo much. The water example helped so much. I was overcomplicating what was inside vs outside of the loop for so long when it was the simplest idea the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field lines around the wire form closed loops that run in the direction of the fingers, as shown in the picture.  That direction is from the base of the fingers towards the finger tips.  This means that inside the wire loop, the magnetic field lines are pointing into the paper that the drawing is printed on, and outside the wire loop, the magnetic field lines are pointing out of the paper that the drawing is printed on.